# Is there a way to set a default font in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I know that there is a way to set a default font on Google Docs, but I was wondering if there's a way to set a default font in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can find online, there is no way easy way to set a default font on Sheets.

The only thing I could find on the subject is [this Product Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/IyLe3vlYmqA) from 2016: "This does not work on Google Sheets. It even says that in the Help article that you linked to: "Note: At the moment, this feature isn't available for spreadsheets."

Answer (score 5):

Now, you can set the default font. However, the choice is quite limited.

1. In the menu bar, click on `Format>Theme`.
2. A panel appears on the right side of your screen. Click on `Customize`.
3. Select your font.

See the themes menu, here:

[image: Custom theme menu]

Comment: Thanks for adding this! This is helpful, however not quite the goal of the original question. In your solution it looks like you need to set the default font every time you open a new Sheet. Is there a way to set the default font in the them so that it gets applied to all new Sheets as well?

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter Yeah, no... There is unfortunately no option for all new Sheets. It is a shame, isn't? I always have to change  manually for a fixed width font...

Comment: Note also that this doesn't allow you to set the font *size*; only the font and colors

Answer (score 2):

As the OP already said on [their answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119879/88163), at this time this is not a built-in Google Sheets feature, but there are some workarounds that we could use:

1. Use a spreadsheet as a template to create new spreadsheets.
2. Use an add-on / script to make it easier to set cell formats.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that if you highlight the entire sheet and change the font, and then ensure to double click inside the cell before typing, it will keep the new default font.

Not the easiest, but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to keep formatting is to add rows or columns in the middle of the sheet instead of at the end.

If you insert a row then it will insert the row with the formatting (font, etc.) of where you're inserting. Definitely not ideal but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When starting a document, select all cells, then select the font, font size, etc... you want. These will be applied to all cells of the sheet and will therefore constitute a "default font" on your sheet. Once you are satisfied with the settings, you can save your blank file as a template, and duplicate it whenever you want to create a sheet with the same "default font"...

Comment: Good try, but whenever you enter new text into a cell in google sheet. It changed the font color /style back to the "google default" one overwriting the previous setting of the whole google sheet.    I suspect that  it is a bug in Google Sheet.  Entering new text should NOT overwrite existing color styling of that cell.  .... Long sigh....

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently built into Google Sheets, which is a ridicules as it's integral for productive workflow.
I have found a much easier work around then what was provided in this thread so far.

I saw there was a table styles add-on you could include, but it did not install for me.